# YouTube embedded video params not working

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api

```
https://github.com/Joe1992w/laravel-media-embed
```

to generate Youtube / Vimeo embedded iframes here is my code

```
   public function update_video_url($url){
        $whitelist = ['YouTube', 'Vimeo'];
        $params = [
            'autoplay' => 1,
            'loop' => 1,
            'controls' => 1

        ];
        $data=\LaravelMediaEmbed::parse($url, $whitelist,$params);
        return $data->getEmbedCode();
    }
```

but it seem that params defined on Youtube forums not working controllers are not hiding still share and watch later is showing

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop
```

you can check this to by Youtube js Api http://jsfiddle.net/fgkrj/

Answer (score 1):

The [`controls`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls) parameter only removes the player controls (e.g. Pause, Play, Volume).

**Watch Later** and **Share** are not part of player controls. Both, along with the video title, used to be part of the [`showinfo`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo) parameter and setting it to `showinfo = 0` would hide all of them. However, `showinfo` parameter has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018) and ignored since September 25, 2018.

Currently, there is no way to remove them and I don't think there will be plans to as they believe these are an important part of YouTube’s core user experience.